# Why do German umlauts and sharp s (ß) work without a package in LaTeX?

Tags: packages, languages, input-encodings

I am used to the fact that LaTeX will only know letters like ä, ö, ü, or ß if I use packages like

```
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Today, I tried LaTeX on a Mac for the first time, using the MacTeX distribution and texmaker. Without writing down any packages, all umlauts and ß were accepted correctly from scratch.
Why is that and will the usage of special letters without using the packages cause any problems?

Comment: Since 2018, the default encoding for files is UTF-8, so `inputenc` is not needed for files so encoded. You still need `fontenc`, though, if you want better hyphenation of words with accented and “special” characters. Note also that `ucs` and `utf8x` have been unmaintained for several years and are not recommended.

Comment: Interesting to know! There are a lot of tutorials out there still using the packages mentioned. As a relative newbie, I never noticed that these are deprecated. Thanks for advice! Is there any official documentation about when these changes happened, though?

Comment: @TiMauzi Here: https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews28.pdf All significant changes to the LaTeX kernel are announced with a LaTeX News issue, which you can find [here](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since the April 2018 release, LaTeX considers UTF-8 as default input encoding

[image]

[image]

Thus calling `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` at the start is no longer required. If a file has a different encoding than UTF-8, the proper encoding should, of course, be declared.

The `utf8x` add-on, together with the `ucs` package, used to be needed for some special application or, mostly, for typesetting Greek. The situation has very much changed and `utf8x` should be avoided (also `ucs`) as it has been unmaintained for several years and `utf8` (the default) behaves much better.

On the other hand, loading `fontenc` is still required in order to use the T1 encoding and get better results with hyphenation of words containing accented letters or special glyphs used in European languages.

Why don't manuals and guides mention this? Because inertia prevails. :-(

Comment: I've just asked Overleaf to update their templates to reflect exactly this!

Comment: Sent a message to the Austrian tutorial site's admins, as well... (Link: https://latex.tugraz.at/latex/tutorial)

Comment: @egreg Shouldn't `inputenc` be used at all or not just with the `utf8` option?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I'd like to add that in 2022 (after April 2018?)  `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is not just *unnecessary* but can be *harmful* for **certain engines**.

I used to include these packages in BibTex, together with `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` , following some old tutorials.
ä ö ü worked fine but every ß was complied to SS.

This problem is solved by this question and an another explanition here( see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641959/278331)

In 2022 for *unicode-aware engine*s as **XeTex** and **LuaTex**, just delete all of these package declarations

```
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

then you would be able use all letters from `ä` to `ß` in source code directly

Edit:
`\usepackage[ngerman]` is still required for a **correct hyphenation**

Comment: ... if you are using an unicode-aware engine (XeTeX and LuaTeX). For pdfTeX, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is more or less required if you are writing anything more complicated than English

Comment: @ Phelype Oleinik  Thank you for this introduction on difference among engines! I have corrected my answer.

Comment: You still need `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` or words won’t be correctly hyphenated.

Comment: @Javier Bezos Thank you I have not noticed hyphenations. I have concluded this point in the answer .