# German umlauts are OK, but ß appears as "SS"

Tags: xetex, characters, german

I'm writing a paper in German, and these are my settings for font:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding

\usepackage{zi4} % Pretty font for Source Code

\usepackage{kpfonts} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document
\usepackage{tgadventor}  % Font for the title page
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmtt}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\rmdefault}
```

All ä, ö, ü appear OK, but the `ß` does not. The phrase in my TeX source code is "...eine größere API ...", but in PDF it looks like this:

[image]

I'm using [XeTex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX) version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 ([TeX Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX_Live) 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex), \write18 enabled.

==== Update ======

Just to answer @wipet and @Mico's questions:

Basically I'm pretty naive about LaTeX environment settings. Many years ago I used [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) on Windows for editing and building my papers. MikTex was in use, and that is why [pdfTeX](http://tug.org/applications/pdftex/) came into play.

Now I'm using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) + Latex Workshop on a [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) box for building papers. The manual of that "LaTeX Workshop" says it works best with [TeX Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX_Live), so I used TeX Live. But I did not know pdfTeX and TeX Live are two different things and they are not compatible. So you see the funny mix of settings.

*Come on professors and classmates, why are we not using Markdown for papers...?*

Ah, speaking of "palatino clone", I think the font "tgpagella" is more appropriate for that reputation? I used tgpagella for my Diplomarbeit, and I really liked it. But now I guess I'm not as sharp as before, and now I prefer the roundness and airy-ness of the kpfonts....

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Please, give full example, which generates SS instead ß. Not only a code snippet which does not say where is your problem. Of course, if you are using XeTeX then use Unicode fonts and no fontenc.

Comment: your complete font setup is for pdflatex. Neither fontenc, zi4, kpfonts or tgadventor are suitable for xelatex.

Comment: Off-topic: Just curious why you appear to treat 'kpfonts' as some kind of "Adobe Utopia". I would think that calling kpfonts a Palladio clone would be more appropriate.

Comment: @wipet  I answered your questions in the updated text. Thanks!

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer  I answered your questions in the updated text. Thanks!

Comment: @Mico I answered your questions in the updated text. Thanks!

Comment: pdflatex, xelatex and texlive are *three* different things. The comments were about your use of xelatex. In view of your edit: you probably don't want to use it. use pdflatex.

Comment: @NicoleNaumann you say: "pdflatex and texlive are two different things and they are not compatible". It is not true. texlive is TeX distribution (like MikTeX), both these TeX distributions include TeX engines: pdftex, xetex, luatex. You can select what TeX engine you want to use. And you can select, what format of TeX use: plain TeX, LaTeX, OpTeX, ConTeXt.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're using XeLaTeX, you shouldn't be loading the `fontenc`, `inputenc`, and `kpfonts` packages. Instead, you should be loading the `fontspec` and `kpfonts-otf` packages.

The code below selects the packages to be loaded based on whether either pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX is in use. (If either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is in use, care is also taken to match the x-heights across the serif, sans-serif, and monospaced fonts.) With this precaution in place, umlauts and the `ß` character are typeset correctly in all three cases.

Oh, I wouldn't run `\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmtt}` under pdfLaTeX since it nullifies loading the `zi4` package.

The following screenshot was obtained by executing the code below under XeLaTeX:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
  \usepackage{kpfonts} % Palatino clone text (serif) and math font
  \usepackage{zi4}        % monospaced font (Consolas/Inconsolata)
  \usepackage{tgadventor} % sans-serif font (clone of ITC Avantgarde Gothic)
\else
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
  \setmonofont{Consolas}[Scale=MatchLowercase] % or some other suitable font
  \ifxetex
    \setsansfont{texgyreadventor}[%
      % Set the path as needed for your OS and TeX distribution:
      Path =/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/,
      Scale=MatchLowercase,
      Extension     = .otf,
      UprightFont   = *-regular,
      BoldFont      = *-bold,
      ItalicFont    = *-italic,
      BoldItalicFont= *-bolditalic]
  \else
    \setsansfont{TexGyre Adventor}[Scale=MatchLowercase] 
  \fi
\fi
  
%\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmtt} % why?? 
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\rmdefault}  % serves no discernible purpose

\begin{document}

das größere Übel

\sffamily
das größere Übel

\ttfamily
das größere Übel

\end{document}
```

Comment: Loading `zi4` is completely useless, given the following redefinition of `\ttdefault`.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks. I've incorporated your comment and have also provided a major update to how the adventor fonts are loaded under XeLaTeX.

Comment: Hi Mico, thank you very much for your help! Your code basically works but unfortunately my Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon v5.2.7 does not have the kpfonts-otf installed by default, I found this package on ctan but I'm too naive to install that per hand. Do you know if there's an easier way to install this package? All the characters appeared correctly in my paper now, but the text font just looks stupid for now.

Comment: @NicoleNaumann - I'm afraid I don't know Linux all that well. (In fact, I know very little about Linux. Sorry!) Is there any chance you could update your TeX distribution to either TeXLive2021 or (better still) TeXLive2022? [This page](https://www.latex-project.org/get/) could be a useful starting point.

Comment: Hi Mico, I just followed the installation instruction of the kpfonts-otf package, just four steps, the final step of "mktexlsr" is important. Then voila! The manual installation is easier than it looks like! Now my paper looks pretty again, thank you very much! Ah by the way, I use "Dank Mono" for the mono font in my paper, it looks really pretty!

Answer (score 11):

The problem is in the fact, that first 256 slots of Unicode (which is roughly speaking the same as iso-latin1 encoding) differs from TeX 8bit encoding used in 90s, agreed at the conference in Cork, and named T1. The T1 encoding includes SS at the slot 223 but Unicode declares ß here. The reason for T1 was: the SS is uppercase of ß and the ß itself is at the slot 255 in T1: the difference of all slots of uppercase/lowercase letters in T1 is constant: 32.

There was special methods how to convert ß (slot 223) from iso-latin1 input encoding to the slot 255 from T1 encoding. A huge of fonts for TeX were created in T1 encoding in 90s. For example in LaTeX, the `[latin1]{inputenc}` package sets the ß as active character and converts it to `\ss`. The `[T1]{fontenc}` package defines the `\ss` macro as slot 255. If you have Unicode input (represented by UTF-8), then ß is two-byte character and `[utf8]{inputenc}` sets the first byte as active and converts these two bytes to `\ss` macro. But when you are using Unicode TeX engines (XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX) then the `[utf8]{inputenc}` is ignored with the message:

```
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
```

so, ß isn't converted to `\ss` and it cannot be converted to T1 encoding. This is the core of your problem.

But now, we have Unicode engines: luatex, xetex, Unicode fonts and we need not to carry about this problem because ß on input is equal to ß in font.

The problem is visible very clearly when you use OpTeX without loading the Unicode font:

```
hello: ß
\bye
```

The result is hello: SS, because the T1 encoded font is preloaded into the format. And the log file and the terminal report the warning:

```
WARNING l.2: Unicode font was not loaded.
```

If you select Unicode font family, then the problem disappear:

```
\fontfam[adventor]
hello: ß
\bye
```

because ß on the input is ß in the font.

Comment: Very nice explanation.

Comment: Thank you wipet! This is really solid knowledge for every LaTeX user!